# Drop duplicates that share part of a string within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following dataframe

```
Number
148621
645121
456
645121-A
1234123
```

Is there a way to remove duplicates ignoring certain characters? '-A' in this case.
The expected result would be:

```
Number
148621
456
645121-A
1234123
```

Comment: How would you know which one to remove? For your case, you removed the first record, but is that consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripping it to make them duplicates to check uniqueness and then filtering:

```
>>> is_uniq_custom = ~df.Number.str.rstrip("-A").duplicated(keep="last")
>>> is_uniq_custom 
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
Name: Number, dtype: bool

>>> df.Number[is_uniq_custom]
0      148621
2         456
3    645121-A
4     1234123
Name: Number, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temporary column and use that as the filter:

```
(
    df.assign(tmp=df.Number.map(lambda s: s.rstrip("-A")))
      .drop_duplicates("tmp", keep="last")
      .drop("tmp", axis=1, inplace=False)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a general use case, you could use regex

```py
df["clean_number"] = df['Number'].str.extract("([0-9]+)")
```

This will extract the first instance of a number seen in the string.

For example:

```py
s = pd.Series(["12345a", "12345-A", "abc12345", "1234abc3435"])
>>> s.str.extract("([0-9]+)")
      0
0  12345
1  12345
2  12345
3   1234
```

Now if you want to drop duplicates then run the following:

```py
df.drop_duplicates(subset='clean_number', keep="last")
```

Set `keep="first"` if you want to keep the first row. Although it looks like you only gave a pandas series, so you could also run

```py
df["clean_number"].unique()
```

This will give you a numpy array of the unique numbers in your list.